# Get the closest time to 24:00:00 between less 23:00:00 to greater 24:00:00 in C#

Tags: c#, datetime, if-statement

I am trying to get the time closer to 24:00:00 between two values, before midnight and after midnight.

EDIT: This is just an an example of what I am trying to do.  In this case I should get both items.

```
var dt1 = new DateTime(2014, 11, 11, 23, 50, 00);
var dt2 = new DateTime(2014, 12, 11, 00, 50, 00);
var l = new List<DateTime>();

for (int i = 0; i < l.Count - 1; i++)
{
    TimeSpan ts1 = new TimeSpan(l[i].Hour, l[i].Minute, l[i].Second);
    TimeSpan ts2 = new TimeSpan(l[i + 1].Hour, l[i + 1].Minute, l[i + 1].Second);

    if (ts1.TotalHours <= 23 && ts2.TotalHours >= 00)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("00:00:00 - {0} {1} \n", ts1, ts2);
    }
}
```

Thank you for any help and advise.

Comment: Do you mean you want to find out which of ts1 and ts2 is closer to 24 hours?

Comment: a sample output and expected output will be helpful

Comment: @Codeek I have not output.

Comment: @juharr that's correct.

Comment: Are you working with absolute times, or with spans?

Comment: And it doesn't work as expected because ... ? I suggest you specify your expectation, as in "if I input foo, it outputs bar but I'm trying to obtain baz"

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I am using timeSpan but if you have a better solution I can change.

Comment: What's the answer to my question? Are you working with times or with time spans? I ask because it looks like you mean to consider times as the input, but then proceed to put them into spans.

Comment: @Alex I am trying to collect data from a database every 6 hours.  I manage to get 06, 12 and 18.  Now I have to get closet to 24 or 00.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I am trying to collect data from a database every 6 hours. I manage to get 06, 12 and 18. Now I have to get closet to 24 or 00

Comment: @doro Do you have the month, day, and year so you can work with DateTimes instead of TimeSpans?  That would make comparing something just before midnight and just after midnight easier.   And exactly what type is `Item1` in your list?

Comment: @juharr I need to get the time closer to 24:00:00.  So I guess we should compare only hours and many be minutes.

Comment: @doro There is no 24:00:00 in 24 hour time. You go to 23:59:59 and then 0:00:00 is next.

Comment: Ok, so what I should use in if?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
        var dt1 = new DateTime(2014, 11, 11, 23, 50, 00);
        var dt2 = new DateTime(2014, 12, 11, 00, 50, 00);

        var dt1temp = new DateTime(dt1.Year, dt1.Month, dt1.Day, 00, 00, 00);
        var dt2temp = new DateTime(dt2.Year, dt2.Month, dt2.Day, 00, 00, 00);

        TimeSpan time1 = new TimeSpan();
        TimeSpan time2 = new TimeSpan();
        TimeSpan time24 = new TimeSpan(24, 0, 0);

        time1 = dt1 - dt1temp;
        time2 = dt2 - dt2temp;

        if (time1.Hours >= 12) time1 = time24 - time1;
        if (time2.Hours >= 12) time2 = time24 - time2;

        string result = "";

        if (time1 < time2) result = "Time1 nearer to 00:00";
        else result = "Time2 nearer to 00:00";
```

Comment: It seems to be what I want.  Thank you katz! :-)

Answer (score 2):

Your question is quite confusing and not totally clear what it is you're trying to achieve, but I've made some assumptions, and come up with what I think maybe what you're after:

```
var l = new List<DateTime> {
    new DateTime(2014, 11, 11, 22, 0, 0),
    new DateTime(2014, 11, 11, 23, 45, 0),
    new DateTime(2014, 11, 11, 23, 55, 0),
    new DateTime(2014, 11, 11, 23, 59, 59),
    new DateTime(2014, 11, 12, 0, 0, 0),
    new DateTime(2014, 11, 12, 0, 4, 0),
    new DateTime(2014, 11, 12, 0, 15, 0),
    new DateTime(2014, 11, 12, 1, 0, 0),
    new DateTime(2014, 11, 12, 10, 0, 0),
};

for (int i = 0; i < l.Count - 1; i++) {

    if (l[i].TimeOfDay.TotalMinutes < 5 || l[i].TimeOfDay.TotalMinutes >= 23*60 + 55) 
        Console.WriteLine("{0} is close to midnight", l[i]);
    else
        Console.WriteLine("{0} is NOT close to midnight", l[i]);

}
```

I've loaded the list of dates/times with some test data, and the code simply prints out whether each date/time is within 5 minutes either side of midnight.

Another attempt at answering you're ambiguous question is as follows:

```
var l = new List<DateTime> {
    new DateTime(2014, 11, 11, 15, 0, 0),   // 15:00:00
    new DateTime(2014, 11, 11, 16, 0, 0),   // 16:00:00
    new DateTime(2014, 11, 11, 17, 0, 0),   // 17:00:00
    new DateTime(2014, 11, 11, 17, 20, 0),  // 17:20:00
    new DateTime(2014, 11, 11, 18, 15, 0),  // 18:15:00
    new DateTime(2014, 11, 11, 19, 0, 0),   // 19:00:00
    new DateTime(2014, 11, 11, 22, 0, 0),   // 22:00:00
    new DateTime(2014, 11, 11, 23, 45, 0),  // 23:45:00
    new DateTime(2014, 11, 11, 23, 50, 00), // 23:50:00
    new DateTime(2014, 12, 11, 00, 50, 00), // 00:50:00
    new DateTime(2014, 11, 12, 1, 0, 0),    // 01:00:00
    new DateTime(2014, 11, 12, 10, 0, 0),   // 10:00:00
};

var time = new TimeSpan(18, 0, 0); // <- Set the target time here
var offsetBefore = new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0, 0).TotalMilliseconds - time.TotalMilliseconds;
var offsetAfter = time.TotalMilliseconds * -1;

var closestBefore =
    l.Aggregate(
        (current, next) =>
            next.AddMilliseconds(offsetBefore).TimeOfDay.TotalMilliseconds > current.AddMilliseconds(offsetBefore).TimeOfDay.TotalMilliseconds
                ? next
                : current);

var closestAfter =
    l.Aggregate(
        (current, next) =>
            next.AddMilliseconds(offsetAfter).TimeOfDay.TotalMilliseconds < current.AddMilliseconds(offsetAfter).TimeOfDay.TotalMilliseconds
                ? next
                : current);

Console.WriteLine("{0} is the closest date/time before {1}.", closestBefore, time);
Console.WriteLine("{0} is the closest date/time after {1}.", closestAfter, time);
Console.WriteLine("00:00:00 - {0} {1} \n", closestBefore, closestAfter);

// OUTPUTS:
//   11/11/2014 17:20:00 is the closest date/time before 18:00:00.
//   11/11/2014 18:15:00 is the closest date/time after 18:00:00.
//   00:00:00 - 11/11/2014 17:20:00 11/11/2014 18:15:00
```

This will return the closest date/time in the list to midnight that is before midnight, and also separately the closest date/time in the list to midnight that is after midnight.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for the answer and code.  However, in my case I should have 2 values, one just before midnight and the other other just after midnight.  Also, if you could use TimeSpan your solution would be closer to my real code.  What I posted are just an example.  Thank you.

Comment: @doro: It does use TimeSpan... DateTime.TimeOfDay returns a TimeSpan object. Although I really have no idea what you are trying to do here with your two values, make you're question clearer so that people have a better chance of helping you.

Comment: I need those two values for performing interpolation.

Comment: You need to edit your answer with all the information you are leaving in the comments. It will be easier for people to take an interest in your question and give you the best answer possible. It is hard when most of the knowledge about your problem is distributed in different comments. People have asked you more then once, so please, edit your answer.

Comment: @FilipeCarvalho: Not sure what you mean... I have been editing my answer as I've understood more about the original question...

Comment: sorry, i didn't tag my comment but it was directed to @doro (i thought it would be implied since i was talking about the question). I think you did a great job trying to answer a question that was ambiguous to say the least. We need more people like you and far from me to imply otherwise

Comment: Ah I see! I was confused when your comment mentioned "edit your answer"... No worries. Thanks.

Comment: my fault sorry i meant question =/

Comment: @BG100 I like your second answer. I am sorry if my question seems to be ambiguous, I was at work and I did my best to simulate my original code.  Anyway, could you also be so kind to tell me about closer to 06:00:00 and 18:00:00?  Thank you.

Comment: @doro: I've amended my second example to work with any target time... just amend the time variable to match any time of day.